# Auto incremental temporary column in conditional select statement

Tags: mysql, select

I am using the following select query to group and calculate a specific column:

```
SELECT `COUNTRY`, sum(`POINT`) as total_mark 
FROM results 
GROUP BY `COUNTRY` 
ORDER by total_mark DESC
```

I would like to add a temporary column that numbers all rows incrementally. I used:

```
(@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber
```

The new column gets created but returns a NULL value for all rows. Can anyone help me to do the grouping and calculation first and the numbering the rows it returns. I tried this:

```
SELECT `COUNTRY`, sum(`POINT`) as total_mark, (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber 
FROM results 
GROUP BY `COUNTRY` 
ORDER by total_mark DESC
```

I still only get NULL values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize `@cnt` to `0`.

You should also do the ordering in a subquery. Otherwise, the row numbers may be assigned before ordering.

```
SELECT country, total_mark, (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber 
FROM (
    SELECT `COUNTRY`, sum(`POINT`) as total_mark
    FROM results 
    GROUP BY `COUNTRY` 
    ORDER by total_mark DESC
) AS x
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0) AS vars
```

Note that if you're using MySQL 8.x you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function instead of a session variable.

Comment: I know that they might be, but in practice (prior to 8), they never are

Comment: Probably true. I've seen some weird effects with session variables, I may be misremembering which ones necessitated subqueries.